# Joomla URL junk

Tags: url, joomla, seo, sef

So, I've set up a site and have Search Engine Friendly URLs on YES, I've set up page aliases and my main URLs are fine but those pages, for some reason, can be accessed trough some weird links like mysite.com/component/content/article/17-category/61-article-name.html instead of just mysite.com/category/article-name.html like I want it and like I have it in my sitemap.

Why is joomla generating these redundant URLs and how to get rid of them (so when somebody clicks on them in google it takes him to 404)?

Thanks

PS. answer on question [How to clean up Joomla! URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104469/how-to-clean-up-joomla-urls) does not help me.

Answer (score 0):

As per http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-june-2013/item/1054-duplicate-pages-joomla-causes-errors-solutions

I used 301 Redirect in .htaccess file to redirect from doubled URLs